# Django IntegerField retrieves a 0 as a None value when using MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, django

Django has started retrieving all of my IntegerField with a value of zero as None instead of as a zero.

This is happening across all of my models. I recently updated mysql-connector-python so I am not sure if that could be the problem.

Does anyone know of a global setting or bug that would cause Django to start doing this across all of my models?

example:

```
class Brands(models.Model):
   brand_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   brand_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=512)
   blacklisted = models.IntegerField()
   blacklisted_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
   date_created = models.DateTimeField()

   class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'brands'
```

The values for blacklisted are all being retrieved as None instead of 0.
They are stored as a 0 in the database.

Django version 2.2.1

MySQL InnoDB

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you changed your models recently? Can you try `Python manage.py makemigrations` to update the sechema?

Comment: How do you check this? What code are you using that returns `None`?

Comment: @Azy_Crw4282 I have not changed most of my models. I did add a few new models. I also ran a migration about the same time this issue started, however, all of my models are not managed by django. I just tried a new makemigration and migration and it did not fix anything

Comment: @dirkgroten It is showing as a None on the test server. I also have overwritten get_context_data to add a simple print and the values are being printed as None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround for this bug: add `'use_pure': True` to database OPTIONS.
This forces mysql-connector-python to use pure python connection instead of C extension, where I believe the bug lives, see [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30469)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': os.environ['MYSQL_DATABASE'],
        'USER': os.environ['MYSQL_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['MYSQL_PASSWORD'],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'use_pure': True,
    }
}
```

Or alternatively you can set this in the settings.py file

`'OPTIONS': {'use_pure': True }`

Comment: Great, happy to help